# My return value returns an error

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

I have a method called RandomInt, that returns a random number. However, when I try to return the value, it gives me an error, stating that the variable cannot be found. I can't use it as a parameter either, because when I call it in another method, it'll return `0`. Any help?

```
public static int randomInt(int low, int high) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double x = Math.random();
        int e = (int) x * high / low;
     }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding why you have the loop inside the method.

Comment: The scope of e is limited to the `for` loop and the `return` is outside, as it should be. So declare `int e;` outside the loop.

Comment: @DSlomer64 I don't see how that would be useful, as OP would just overwrite `e` a bunch of times.

Comment: Heh... good point, @hexafraction. I was just fixing his compile error not his logic error. He probably should just lose the for loop since he says "A random number" is returned.

Comment: Also, `(int)x` will always be 0.

Comment: The source code is an impertinence. Please don't ever post something like this again.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the scope of a variable is bound by `{` `}` characters (in Javascript this is not the case). That means if a variable is declared in a set of `{}` (curly brackets), it cannot be referenced outside of these brackets.

This is the case in your code. The variable `e` is declared in the loop, so you can not use it in the function's return statement. I would suggest declaring `e` right before the lop.

Answer (score 1):

In java whenever a variable is declared, it have a certain scope. When you declare a variable inside a loop, it is only accessible inside that loop. Because the variable you are returning is declared inside the for loop, this is why it is giving an error. Try declaring a variable outside the loop and then access that in the for loop. You code will look like this :

```
public static int randomInt(int low, int high) 
{
    int e = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
       double x = Math.random();
       e = (int) x * high / low;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method can return only one value (in your case one `int`), but it can be a composite value (array or object). In this case, you are better off having a loop call your method a bunch of times, and do whatever it needs to do with the result.

Technically, `int e`'s scope is inside the loop body since it is declared inside there. The following code will generate 10 random numbers, and return the last one (as the last one overwrites the 9th, which overwrites the 8th, ...):

```
public static int randomInt(int low, int high){
    int e;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        double x=Math.random();
        e=(int)x*high/low;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're declaring the variable `e` inside the loop, then trying to reference it from outside that loop. The below should work:

```
public static int randomInt(int low, int high)
{
    int e;

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        double x=Math.random();
        e=(int)x*high/low;
    }

    return e;
}
```

Comment: This will work in only the literal "not a syntax error" sense. This is an awful lot of code for `return 0`.